# Solving Diophantine Equations using Decomposition Method.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

**Decomposition Method:**

> This method consists of writing the equation as $f(x_1,x_2,x_3,...x_n)=0$ in the form $$f_1(x_1,x_2,x_3,...x_n)f_2(x_1,x_2,x_3,...x_n)...f_{k}(x_1,x_2,x_3,...x_n)=a,\text{ where }a\in\mathbb{Z}.$$ Given the prime factoriazation of $a$ we obtain finitely many decompositions into $k$ integers factors $a_1,a_2,...,a_k.$ Each such decomposition yields a system of equation: $$f_1(x_1,x_2,x_3,...x_n)=a_1$$
>   $$f_2(x_1,x_2,x_3,...x_n)=a_2$$
>   $$...$$
>   $$f_k(x_1,x_2,x_3,...x_n)=a_k$$
>   Solving all such systems gives the complete set of solutions to $(1).$

I have to use this method to solve the following equations: $$(xy-7)^2=x^2+y^2, \text{ where }x,y\geq 0.$$
And $$x^2(y-1)+y^2(x-1)-1=0,\text{ where }x,y\geq 0.$$

I am having difficulty in factorising the equations. Is there any known technique to factorize such equations or a heuristic which should be followed while solving such equations? Moreover, if someone is interested in giving solutions to the equation mentioned above, please also include your thought process involved while solving the problems.